# Clabel and createText not in align

Tags: java, swt

When i create a label and multiline text.
I see the result as below -
[image]

But i want the label to be at the top and not in center of the multiline text field.
I want the result as below -
[image]

Here is the code -

```
getWidgetFactory().createCLabel(parent, Configuration, SWT.LEFT); //$NON-NLS-1$
 Text configuration = getWidgetFactory().createText(parent, "",SWT.MULTI|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
GridData dataConfig = new GridData();
dataConfig.widthHint = 175;
dataConfig.heightHint = 175;
configuration.setLayoutData(dataConfig);
```

Comment: You should take a look at the layout examples that are given here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
This way, you can make an educated choice on which layout to pick for your entire GUI, which depends on what other components you'll be adding and where.

Comment: thanks, but its a legacy project, i cant make a choice now on that. I have just the authority to edit it and make the requested change

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a new `CLabel` and set its x-y position directly. If your application can be resized in a way such that the label should change position, then this does mean that you have to add a resize listener for this. That's one reason why layout managers are preferred when possible.

Comment: I just now found out the solution for it, using GridData for label too and set it to SWT.TOP, it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using GridData for label too and set it to SWT.TOP, it solves the issue.

GridData labelData = new GridData();
labelData.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;

Using the above Griddata set the layout for the label.